# Override attribute in partial class

Tags: c#, attributes, .net-4.5

I have class autogenerated by tool:

```
[SomeAttribute(1)]
public partial class A
{
   ...
}
```

I need to change attribute, but if I put in other file:

```
[SomeAttribute(2)]
public partial class A
{
   ...
}
```

I get an error:

> Duplicate 'SomeAttribute' attribute.

Is there a way to override the attribute in partial class?
Some hack?

Comment: Do you control`SomeAttribute`?

Comment: @Jamiec No, this is .NET attribute.

Comment: Why don't you just override the autogenerated code?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Because, I must remember to change it after each generation. This is bad practise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attribute is only allowed multiple times if the [`AllowMultiple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.allowmultiple(v=vs.110).aspx) property is set to true on the `AttributeUsageAttribute` which adorns the attribute itself.

If your `SomeAttribute` does not have this, then there is no way to override this behaviour.

Comment: can you write a simple example how to do that for a custom class?

Comment: @T.Todua its all in the docs. Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes